# Mips assembly Calculator Equation Parse

Tags: parsing, assembly, mips, calculator, storing-data

I am making a mips assembly language type of calculator. It gets an equation as the data and I have to parse the equation and follow PEMDAS (order of operations). I can not seem to figure out how to parse and store the string in order for me to do this. I understand that you have to check the hex value of the equation to know what mathematical problem to solve, but don't know how to code it. Also after we multiply two numbers how do you put the answer back into the equation to continue iterating through it. Some code is below, that I worked up, that needs accomplish this. This equation is just an example. Parentheses and exponents aren't used in this. Since this is assembly I didn't put my exact code in as that would be tons of lines but I drew an outline and what I needs fixing or help on and what I have and understand. If i can understand the parse and how the equation and numbers are stored I can probably fix the rest myself so really I just need help at the parse and pemdasone, two, and three labels.

```
.globl division
.globl multiplication
.globl addition
.globl subtraction
.globl end
.globl PemdasOne
.globl PemdasTwo
.globl PemdasThree
.globl parse

.data
a: .half 2
b: .half 3
c: .half 8
d: .half 35
exp: .asciiz "b:=26/a-c+b"

.text
parse:
    (HELP!This is the part that needs work.) (HELP! Read and store     expression)
    (HELP! Create iterator to keep spot in the equation?)

pemdasone:
    (HELP! Check if ascii value at iterator is * or /)
    (UNDERSTAND: if so branch or jump to math equation)
    (UNDERSTAND: if not branch or jump to pemdastwo)
pemdastwo:
    (HELP! check if ascii value at iterator is + or -, reiterate through equation with updated values after pemdasone is done with what it does)
    (UNDERSTAND: if so branch or jump to math equation)
    (UNDERSTAND: if not branch or jump to pemdasthree)
pemdasthree:
    (HELP! check if equation is completed. Store answer in variable b so it is updated from the input value to the answervalue.)
    (UNDERSTAND that if it is done jump to end label)

multiplication: 
    (HELP! get number before the ascii value of * and fter the ascii value of * and store them in registers for the equation.)
    (UNDERSTAND: how to do the mathmatical operator with two numbers.)
    (HELP! store answer in equation so you can keep doing the equation)
    (UNDERSTAND: that jump or branch back to pemdasone)
division:
    (All the math parts are the same help and understands just with new operator and jump and branch locations)
addition:
    (Same help and understands as divide and multiply except jump to pemdastwo)
subtraction:
    (Same as addition)
end:
    (UNDERSTAND that you store the answer into the variable it tells you to)
    (HELP! with memory and where we stored the answer)
```

Comment: Write the program in C, Java or some other language that you're familiar with first (using as few library functions as you can). Then transcribe that into MIPS assembly using a MIPS instruction set reference (i.e. _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_).